# I have no images showing, launch screen, app icon etc, any ideas as to why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi I have an app that is almost ready and I am trying to add my launch screen , app icon and background image, and none of these work, all my images are the right size and format but they just dont show up when I run the app, I have no errors showing up and my background image works on the simulator but not on a real device ( the other images dont work at all ).
Any ideas as to why? thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the device und running it again?

Answer (score 0):

For your Launch screen and the app icon you need to put the images into the correct boxes in the images.xcassets area.  The icon goes into the AppIcon asset, and the launch screen image goes into the LaunchImage asset.  Below are screenshots taken from Xcode.

Launch Screen

[image: Launch Screen asset]

App Icon image

[image: App Icon asset]

If you haven't used assets before, all you do is drag the image that you imported into your project and drop it into the corresponding box in the asset.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this is what I have been doing and it doesn't work for some reason , I am suspecting there is some box somewhere that I need to tick or undo or something like that because every image is not working.